# What does a "carton" here looks like?

Tags: meaning

I was looking for the definition of a *six-pack* and Google definition states it is:
 *a carton containing six bottles or cans*. From [OALD](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/+carton), I noticed that a carton can have several kinds:

> 1. a light cardboard or plastic box or pot for holding goods, especially food or liquid; the contents of a carton, or
> 2. a large container in which goods are packed in smaller containers

So, how does a carton look like in this case of a six-pack?

Comment: Use OALD for the other definition: http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/+six-pack

Comment: Be aware that there's also another definition: "six-pack: (informal) strong stomach muscles that are clearly defined across someone's stomach".

Comment: @Matt I need me some of that :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a couple of possibilities:

[image: http://www.grogonwheels.com.au/system/products/images/1533/product/UDL_Gin_Tonic_6_Cans.jpg?1292017561]

[image: https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR3Js60V4bCvrYHsH06_XQ7qp-gImhA1CTe8lMVLdkOxChuTgz36g]